# Fit textLabel in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` cell, with some text and it is too long so I want it to be automatically resize it. Here is what I have tried:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

//set colors
UIColor *garnetColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:85.0f/255.0f green:0/255.0f blue:3/255.0f alpha:1.0];
UIColor *garnetOffSetColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:127.0f/255.0f green:1/255.0f blue:6/255.0f alpha:1.0];

UIColor *uAlbanyGoldColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:175.0f/255.0f green:120/255.0f blue:40/255.0f alpha:1.0];
UIColor *uAlbanyGoldOffSetColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:190.0f/255.0f green:135/255.0f blue:40/255.0f alpha:1.0];
//    UIColor *uAlbanyPurpleColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:78/255.0f green:26/255.0f blue:128/255.0f alpha:1.0];

UIColor *RPIRedColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:158/255.0f green:8/255.0f blue:3/255.0f alpha:1.0];
UIColor *RPIRedOffSetColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:206/255.0f green:12/255.0f blue:12/255.0f alpha:1.0];

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

    }
   //more code for the cells

}
```

So is there another way to resize the text so it will fit?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth will not works for you.

You need to use heightForRowAtIndexPath method. Below is the sample of that method.

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

```
float cellHeight = [STRING_THAT_YOU_WANT_TO_DISPLAY sizeWithFont:COMMENT_FONET_NEW constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(contentWidth - 65 - 10 - 10, 400)].height;

return cellHeight ;
```

}

Hope it works for you :)

Comment: I'm trying to set the width not height

Comment: and I don't want to display one string I want all the cells to be this way

Comment: Ohh I see... I don't know that.

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: Don't use cell.textLabel.
UILabel *cellLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
cellLabel.frame = YOUR_FRAME;
cellLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
[cell.contentView addSubView:cellLabel];
put this code into if (cell == nil) {} method.
than set text to that label before you return cell.
hope this will works for you

Comment: maybe I need to add a uilabel in the interface builder correct?

Comment: exactlly. You are write

Answer (score 0):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   CGSize maximumCellSize = CGSizeMake(maximumCellWidth, maximumCellHeight);  // (200, 1000) for example
   CGRect textRect = [textToShow boundingRectWithSize:maximumCellSize
                                        options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin)
                                     attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"System" size:15]} // attributes of textToShow
                                        context:nil];
    return textRect.size.height + sumOfHeightsOfOtherConstantStuffInCell;
}
```

Comment: I want this to be done for all the cells so what would I put in "testToSHow"?

Comment: Well you are most likely filling uitableview from some NSArray, so textToShow can be something like array[indexPath.row]

Comment: and then what for "sumOfHeightsOfOtherConstantStuffInCell"?

Comment: try vary it from 0 till you get expected result

Comment: I get this error ` *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException, reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]`